# How to solve a specific isobaric equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the DE

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x^2}{x}$$

I was told that it is isobaric.

Here is my attempt:

Rearrange it, we get

$$(y-x^2)dx- xdy=0$$

Then, let $m=2$ and let $y=vx^m$.

So we get:

$$(vx^2-x^2)dx -x d(mx^2) =0$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here. Can somebody give me some hint on this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients) how to solve this type of equation.

Answer (score 3):

From the DE

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x^2}{x}$$

we have

$$(x^2-y)dx + x dy = 0$$

Here we need to find the integrating factor $\mu(x)$ which is multiplied on both sides.

So let

$$M(x,y) = \mu(x) (x^2 -y)$$

and

$$N(x,y) = x\mu(x)$$

then we set

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = -\mu(x) = \mu(x) + x \mu'(x) = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

And this implies

$$\frac{1}{\mu}d\mu = \frac{-2}{x} dx$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln \mu = -2\ln x + C$$

$$\Rightarrow \mu(x) = K x^{-2}, K \in \mathbb{C} $$

Since we only need to choose a specific $\mu$, we can directly use

$$\mu(x) = x^{-2}$$

Therefore, the DE is transformed into

$$x^{-2}(x^2-y)dx + x^{-2}x dy = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow (1 - \frac{y}{x^2})dx + \frac{1}{x} dy = 0 \cdots (*)$$

where $M = 1 - \dfrac{y}{x^2}, N = \dfrac{1}{x}$.

Hence, we have

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = M(x,y) = 1 - \frac{y}{x^2}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = N(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

And this implies

$$F = \int(1 - \frac{y}{x^2}) dx = x + \frac{y}{x} + f_1(y) \cdots (1)$$

and

$$F = \int \frac{1}{x} dy = \frac{y}{x} + f_2(x) \cdots (2)$$

So combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we have

$$F = x + \frac{y}{x}$$

And given $(*)$, we have

$$F = x + \frac{y}{x} = C \cdots (**)$$

where $C$ is a constant.

Rearrange $(**)$, we finally get

$$y = -x^2 + Cx$$

where $C$ is a constant.

Hope this can help you. You can find more information about this method in almost all undergrad level ODE textbook.

Answer (score 2):

A short solution:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-x^2}{x}\implies \frac{xy'-y}{x^2}=-1 
\implies \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'=-1
$$
$$
\implies \frac{y}{x}=-x+C \implies y=-x^2+Cx.
$$

Comment: Goncalo's ODE solving skills amaze me every time.

Comment: A few more steps would make this answer more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-x^2}{x}$$

$$y'=\frac{y}{x}-x$$

$$y'-\frac{y}{x}=-x$$

$$\frac{1}{x}(y'-\frac{y}{x})=(-x)\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=-1$$

$$\int{\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}}dx=-\int dx$$

$$\frac{y}{x}=-x+C$$

$$y=-x^2+Cx$$